# How to solve algebra equations containing integration and parameters?

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration, special-functions

I'm trying to solve two nonlinear algebra equations for two unknown parameters, `U` and `Tf`. Since some terms in these equations contain integration, and the integration also contains `U` and `Tf`. The main problem I have encountered is that *Mathematica* function `NIntegrate` cannot get numerical results, even in `FindRoot`.

My code is as following:

```
(*Define functions*)

DI1[x_] := 
 E^((Sqrt[K^2 + 2 K U^2 + 4 CC K U^2 + U^4] (-R - x))/(
   2 U) + ((K - U^2) (R + x) - 2 U Log[R + x])/(2 U))
   HypergeometricU[(
   K Sqrt[K^2 + 2 K U^2 + 4 CC K U^2 + U^4] + 
    U^2 Sqrt[K^2 + 2 K U^2 + 4 CC K U^2 + U^4])/(
   K^2 + 2 K U^2 + 4 CC K U^2 + U^4), 0, (
   Sqrt[K^2 + 2 K U^2 + 4 CC K U^2 + U^4] (R + x))/U]

DI2[x_] := 
 E^((Sqrt[K^2 + 2 K U^2 + 4 CC K U^2 + U^4] (-R - x))/(
   2 U) + ((K - U^2) (R + x) - 2 U Log[R + x])/(2 U))
   LaguerreL[-(K Sqrt[K^2 + 2 K U^2 + 4 CC K U^2 + U^4] + 
       U^2 Sqrt[K^2 + 2 K U^2 + 4 CC K U^2 + U^4])/(K^2 + 2 K U^2 + 
       4 CC K U^2 + U^4), -1, (
   Sqrt[K^2 + 2 K U^2 + 4 CC K U^2 + U^4] (R + x))/U]

I1[x_] := NIntegrate[DI1[s], {s, x, ∞}]

I2[x_] := NIntegrate[DI2[s], {s, 0, x}]

(*Define these parameters for simplicity*)

a = Sqrt[K^2 + 2 K U^2 + 4 CC K U^2 + U^4]

C1 := (K Q (K + U^2) Gamma[(K + U^2)/a])/(a U)

C2 := (K Q (K + U^2) Gamma[(K + U^2)/a] DI1[0])/(a U DI2[0]) - (
  K Tf (2 I1[0] - DI1[0]))/(U (I1[0] - DI1[0]) DI2[0])

C3 := (K Q (K + U^2) Gamma[(K + U^2)/a] I1[0])/(a U) - (Tf I1[0] )/(
  I1[0] - DI1[0] )

(*Define equations*)

equ1[U_, Tf_] := -C1*(-U/K DI1'[0] + DI1[0]) + 
   C2*(-U/K DI2'[0] + DI2[0]) - (-Tf DI1[0])/(I1[0] - U/K DI1[0]) == 
  1/Le Exp[-U*Le*R]/R^2 1/
   Integrate[s^-2 Exp[-U*Le*s], {s, R, ∞}]

equ2[U_, Tf_] := 
 1/Le Exp[-U*Le*R]/R^2 1/
   Integrate[
    s^-2 Exp[-U*Le*s], {s, 
     R, ∞}] == (σ + (1 - σ) Tf)^2 Exp[
    Z/2 (Tf - 1)/(σ + (1 - σ) Tf)]

(*FInd roots of equ1 and equ2*)

Block[{K = 1, CC = 2, Q = 1, σ = 0.15, Z = 10, Le = 1, R = 1, 
  Tf = 0.8}, FindRoot[equ1[U, Tf], {U, 1}]]
```

**(Edit)**
I think the main problem is the definition of `I1[x_] := NIntegrate[DI1[s], {s, x, ∞}]`. While `FindRoot` function is running, `NIntegrate` encounters non-numerical results. But if I change the definition from `NIntegrate` to `Integrate`, this integration cannot be calculated out.

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: It seems the standard greeting (above) had not been extended to you.  In particular, don't forget to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problems.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a problem copying and pasting your code, as `HypergeometricU` and `LaguerreL` begin on new lines, but I believe you meant for them to be part of the definitions for `DI1` and `DI2`. Fixing that, the problem of non-numerical integrand comes from undefined global `U`, which can be set inside `Block`, and `FindRoot` attempting to evaluate its argument symbolically, which can be prevented by restricting its argument's definition to numeric values:

```
block[u_,expr_]:=Block[{K=1,CC=2,Q=1,\[Sigma]=0.15,Z=10,Le=1,R=1,Tf=0.8,U=u},expr]
SetAttributes[block,HoldRest]
equ1[U_?NumericQ]:=block[U,equ1[U,Tf]]
```

However, preventing `FindRoot` from manipulating its argument symbolically removes its ability to handle equations, as evaluating the equations numerically returns only true or false, so redefine the equations as functions:

```
equ1[U_, Tf_] := -C1*(-U/K DI1'[0] + DI1[0]) + 
   C2*(-U/K DI2'[0] + DI2[0]) - (-Tf DI1[0])/(I1[0] - U/K DI1[0]) - 
   1/Le Exp[-U*Le*R]/R^2 1/
   Integrate[s^-2 Exp[-U*Le*s], {s, R, \[Infinity]}]

equ2[U_, Tf_] := 
   1/Le Exp[-U*Le*R]/R^2 1/
   Integrate[s^-2 Exp[-U*Le*s], {s, R, \[Infinity]}] - 
   (\[Sigma] + (1 - \[Sigma]) Tf)^2 Exp[Z/2 (Tf - 1)/(\[Sigma] + (1 - \[Sigma]) Tf)]
```

Now calling `FindRoot[equ1[u],{u,1}]` returns a host of errors from divergent `I1[0]` and `Integrate[s^-2 Exp[-U*Le*s], {s, R, \[Infinity]}]`, with the latter requiring `U>0` since `Le=1`. For `I1[0]`, we have

```
block[U, Integrate[DI1[s], {s, 0, Infinity}]] // FullSimplify
```

> $$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{e^{-\frac{(s+1) \left(U^2+\sqrt{U^4+10 U^2+1}-1\right)}{2 U}} HypergeometricU\left(\frac{U^2+1}{\sqrt{U^4+10 U^2+1}},0,\frac{(s+1) \sqrt{U^4+10 U^2+1}}{U}\right)}{s+1} \, ds$$

which again requires `U>0` to converge.

One way to restrict the domain of `FindRoot` to `U>0` is

```
Abs[U] /. FindRoot[equ1[Abs[U]], {U, 1}]
```

> 0.209635

There is no real root for `equ2`:

```
block[U, equ2[U, Tf]] // FullSimplify
```

> ConditionalExpression[-0.206495 + 1/(1 - E^U U Gamma[0, U]), Re[U] > 0]

which is positive for all `U>0`.